# Multiple labels in Prometheus query

Tags: devops, prometheus, promql

I am trying to get an array of label and values inside one JSON from Prometheus.

I have a metric

```
http_server_requests_seconds_count{method="POST", service="application", status="200", uri="/v1/rest/clients/ids"}
```

Using query:

```
count(sum(rate(http_server_requests_seconds_count[5m])) by (method,uri)) by (uri)
```

I get:

```
"result" : [
         {
            "metric" : {
               "uri" : "/v1/rest/clients/ids"
            },
            "value" : [
               1.662458065998E9,
               "1"
            ]
         },
```

However, I would like to get more labels in the `metric` field, such as service, status, uri.
For example:

```
"metric" : {
   "uri" : "/v1/rest/clients/ids",
   "service" : "application",
   "status" : "200",
},
```

Either value aggregation over each unique label

Comment: If you want to count by "uri" you only can have the "uri" label in the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have adjusted my query as follows

```
round(sum(delta(http_server_requests_seconds_count[5m])) by (service, status, uri) >0 )
```